# The type or namespace name 'Configuration' does not exist in the namespace 'WebApiContrib.Formatting.Html'

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm getting this error with my Visual Studio 2012, Console App (it is a self-hosted webApi OWIN project)....

```
The type or namespace name 'Configuration' does not exist in the namespace
'WebApiContrib.Formatting.Html' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

The error is coming from this line ...

```
using WebApiContrib.Formatting.Html.Configuration;
```

I'm also getting a similar error for ...

```
using WebApiContrib.Formatting.Html.Formatters;
using WebApiContrib.Formatting.Html.Locators
```

In the project references I can see...

```
WebApiContrib.Formatting.Html
```

Any ideas how I can fix it please?

Comment: What if you remove that `using` line? Does it harm anything?

Comment: @patrick Hofman, Yes, I then get a red squigly line (and an error if I build it) for `HtmlMediaTypeViewFormatter` and `GlobalViews`

Comment: Why do you use these usings, where are they documented? Have you updated the `WebApiContrib.Formatting.Html` recently?

Comment: @nemesv, I was following a tutorial on using razorEngine to generate an HTML view using self-hosted WebApi. The tutorial source works (https://github.com/Code-Inside/Samples/tree/master/2013/RazorWebApiOwin). But when I try to merge the code into my own project, I get these errors. I have dbl checked and I have all his references in place.

Comment: The tutorial works because it uses an old version of the WebApiContrib.Formatting.Html package. It has been updated since with a few braking changes. So there is no longer a Configration namespace. See Patrick's answer for the solution.

Comment: @nemesv. Thanks very much. I uninstaled it and installed the version used in the project (plus the ..Razor package) and it works. I will now try and figure out how to convert it to the new package version.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/WebApiContrib.Formatting.Html/WebApiContrib.Formatting.Html) the `HtmlMediaTypeViewFormatter` type, and probably others, are found in `WebApiContrib.Formatting.Html.Formatting`. You don't need the `Configuration` namespace.

Check if you have installed all necessary packages and the latest version by using the NuGet package manager:

```
PM> Install-Package WebApiContrib.Formatting.Html
```

Comment: Thanks. When I run the command I get: `already has a reference to 'WebApiContrib.Formatting.Html 2.0.0'`. I tried adding `WebApiContrib.Formatting.Html.Formatting` and commenting out the other 3 but then I get an error `The name 'GlobalViews' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: I think you should try find another tutorial, which isn't outdated. It will provide you with working examples. Try Ctrl+Shift+F10 on the `GlobalViews` class to see if there is a namespace containing that class.

Comment: Yes, this would be ideal. I've been trying many of these tutorials, but OWIN, webapi-self-hosting etc packages seem to be changing a lot. Most I couldnt get to work (probably due to wrong package versions). This was one of the few that had full code available.

Comment: Okay. Then you are much on your own, trying your way through the changes. Good luck ;)

Comment: Did you find a decent tutorial? If so, please add it.